# Find type of Dependency in Aether

Tags: java, maven, aether

When I analyse Maven dependencies with Aether, I often get objects of class

```
org.eclipse.aether.graph.Dependency
```

I want to extract all dependency information (as in the pom) from this object. This is easy for groupId, artifactId, version and classifier, because these are properties of the underlying artifact (using `getArtifact()`) The `<type>` is more difficult.

A dependency can have a type like `<type>ejb</type>`. I need to recover that type. The only related thing I found is `getExtension()`, but this is not quite the same, because artifacts of type `ejb` have extension `jar`.

Can anyone tell me how to find that type information?

Comment: Really running on Aehter or Maven-Resolve?

Comment: I am still on Aether, but I would not mind upgrading.

Comment: If I correctly remember you have to do the mapping manually...but please ask on the dev list for that (maybe a reference with my name).

Comment: Where do I find that list? This sounds like it is not possible to distinguish the types ejb and jar...

Comment: The pom should contain the appropriate packaging ? BTW: Have you checked the packaging ?